# SEO URL, Category vs Location Priority

Tags: seo, url, google-search, clean-urls

We are building a website for listing out brand information. As a reference it is comparable to yelp.com. Basically a brand will belong to a category and an area. From SEO point of view what will be the right url structure? Should higher priority be given to the location or to the category?

In other words should the URL be 
`www.example.com/restaurants/new-york/abc-restaurant` 
or should it of the format
`www.example.com/new-york/restaurants/abc-restaurant`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is necessarily a right or wrong answer here, but thinking about it logically, if i'm looking for a restaurant, I would most likely be looking for one within a certain local area.

So with that in mind, I'd say  `www.example.com/new-york/restaurants/abc-restaurant` would be the most logical and user friendly approach.

You might want to check out some other similar popular sites, so how they are doing it.

Comment: thats one way of looking at it. Perhaps the other way would be looking at how people search. I guess more people would search for "restaurants in New York", so the other format might be better?

Comment: It should't really matter from an SEO perspective if you don't have the keywords in the correct order, URLs are only 1 of many signals, I wouldn't over think it too much.

Comment: Depends on how you organize your site. If /new-york will have content (restaurants, doctors, etc) then perhaps it makes sense to have city listed first. Who is to say the URL scheme of either could not coexist depending on how you structure your data? Maybe user wants to search by curt first... But someone else could search by restaurant first... Look up information architecture for more ideas...

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking at structures like this it is really a case of which type of [taxonomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxonomy) works best for you.

I would usually default to putting the L2 (category) landing page as the first part of the structure.  So if you have a "Restaurants" page go from `/restaurants/location/`; if you have a "New York" page then go `/new-york/restaurant/`.

If you have both then choose as the first level the aspect of the URL that you expect your visitors to start from.  In your case as you are building a geographical first site (you expect your visitors to say 'Given that I am in New York tonight I need a restaurant') I would expect that your best choice would be:

- `/new-york/restaurant/italian/`
- etc.

Answer (score 1):

Search engines will rank the keyword nearest to the domain as the most important, and the keyword nearest to the domain should be the one that's most important to the user. As such, given you're saying in theory you're comparable to Yelp, then my position is that location should be first.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it does not matter which order you choose regarding SEO. To make indexation more efficient, don't forget to include the location in your title meta tag. It helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose any URL structure, thereby making sure that they are clean enough to understand. Personally, I would prefer location first because i would be knowing the location where i am going and then the restaurants and i have checked many of your competitors are also using the same structure.